# How to create a "Send this Newsletter by Email" button to send a Newsletter to all users (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, actionmailer, sendgrid, newsletter

> **EDIT: Solved, check my answer below.**

So I created a scaffold Called `newsletter` that the site owner will be able to create, edit, destroy, etc. When they're happy with that newsletter, they'll be able to send it out by pressing a button that will call `NewslettersController#send`. I originally had my `.deliver_now` bit located under `NewslettersController#create` when I was making the mailer and the newsletter for testing purposes. When I try to move it to the `send` method, however, all of the sudden on my `NewslettersController#index`, `new`, etc. I get an error saying that the Mailer's view cannot access the Newsletter's attributes. Why is this happening and why does it work with the `create` method only?

For reference, the `Mailer` is called `Monthly` and the scaffold is `Newsletter`.

**The error:**

```
NoMethodError in Newsletters#index
undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass

  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p><%= @newsletter.subject %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.body %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.link %></p>
  </body>
```

**NewslettersController**

```
  def send(monthly)
    Monthly.monthly(@newsletter).deliver_now
  end
```

**`monthly.html.erb` (The mailer's view)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p><%= @newsletter.subject %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.body %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.link %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Relevant Logs:**

```
Started GET "/newsletters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-06 20:08:04 -0400
Started GET "/newsletters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-06 20:08:04 -0400
Processing by NewslettersController#index as HTML
Processing by NewslettersController#index as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"
  Rendered monthly/monthly.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.2ms)
  Rendered monthly/monthly.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.2ms)

Monthly#monthly: processed outbound mail in 8.3ms

Monthly#monthly: processed outbound mail in 8.3ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass):
     5:   </head>
     6:   <body>
     7:     <h1>Hello</h1>
     8:     <p><%= @newsletter.subject %></p>
     9:     <p><%= @newsletter.body %></p>
    10:     <p><%= @newsletter.link %></p>
    11:   </body>
  app/views/monthly/monthly.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_monthly_monthly_html_erb___3456442674425673730_70162508652140'
  app/mailers/monthly.rb:4:in `monthly'
  app/controllers/newsletters_controller.rb:8:in `send'



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass):
     5:   </head>
     6:   <body>
     7:     <h1>Hello</h1>
     8:     <p><%= @newsletter.subject %></p>
     9:     <p><%= @newsletter.body %></p>
    10:     <p><%= @newsletter.link %></p>
    11:   </body>
  app/views/monthly/monthly.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_monthly_monthly_html_erb___3456442674425673730_70162508652140'
  app/mailers/monthly.rb:4:in `monthly'
  app/controllers/newsletters_controller.rb:8:in `send'
```

Let me know if I'm missing some information

**EDIT: Added `monthly.rb`**

```
class Monthly < ApplicationMailer
    def monthly(newsletter)
        @newsletter = newsletter
        mail to: User.pluck(:email)

    end
end
```

**EDIT 2: Added `before_action :set_newsletter`:**

```
before_action :set_newsletter, only: [:send, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def set_newsletter
  @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:id])
end
```

> **EDIT 3: New issues.** I no longer have errors for the index or show methods, but get the same errors as before when trying to send the
>   newsletter. Below is the code, but please be aware, names have changed
>   in order to be more self-explanatory.

**Error:**

```
undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p><%= @newsletter.subject %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.body %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.link %></p>
</body>
```

**NewslettersController#send_newsletter**

```
  def send_newsletter
    Monthly_Mailer.monthly(@newsletter).deliver_now
    flash[:notice] = "Newsletter has been sent."
    redirect_to newsletter_path(@newsletter.id)
  end
```

**Routes**

```
get :send_newsletter, to: 'newsletters#send_newsletter', as: :send_newsletter
```

**Monthly_Mailer.rb**

```
class Monthly_Mailer < ApplicationMailer
    def monthly(newsletter)
        @newsletter = newsletter
        mail to: User.pluck(:email)
    end
end
```

**Button to send newsletter on `show.html.erb`**

```
<%= link_to "Send Newsletter by email", :controller => "newsletters", :action => "send_newsletter", :id => @newsletter.id %>
```

**Relevant log entries show that `newsletter.id` is being passed correctly:**

```
Processing by NewslettersController#send_newsletter as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets `@newsletter` in your controller?  And what does the `monthly` method look like?

Comment: @cschroed  `@newsletter` is set with the `before_action :set_newsletter` `private` method that rails uses to set the `@newsletter` by default for all CRUD actions. I added the `monthly.rb` in the edit. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you include the `before_action`, `set_newsletter`, and action code here?  Typically, an action like `index` doesn't set up a single `@newsletter` but a collection of `@newsletters`.

Comment: @cschroed `set_newsletter` isn't called before `index`, only before actions that need to reference a specific newsletter. Check `EDIT 2` for the code. I apologize for the miscommunication if I said it was called before `index` as well

Comment: Your log says `Processing by NewslettersController#index`.  Is `index` the action that is calling `NewslettersController#send` and then `Monthly.monthly`?

Comment: @cschroed No, sir. The `send` action isn't being called by `index`

Comment: Is `params[:id]` being passed to your `send` action?  If you add lines for `Rails.logger.debug("params: #{params.inspect}")` and `Rails.logger.debug("@newsletter: #{@newsletter.inspect}")` in the `send` action what does it say in the log?

Comment: Please post your `index` method.

Comment: @cschroed sorry man I didn't mean to be rude and not reply, I'm away from my computer until like an hour from now. I'll go ahead and see what's getting passed then though and post it. Pavan, from memory I know that it's the default scaffold index method "@newsletters = Newsletter.all" but if it is different I will post it in an edit here and a few minutes. Thank you to both of you for your responses. I'll take a closer look at the index method

Comment: I've posted the Edit. Check for the blockquotes.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your input. I've fixed it all. I must've done something dumb in my coffee-less daze yesterday. I'm posting a tutorial-esque answer and I would appreciate your criticism of it here in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> **How to create a "Send this Newsletter by Email"**

This will allow your users to create, edit, and delete Newsletters just like any post, and then send them out once they're satisfied with them.

This assumes you've gotten your `environment` files all set up and can successfully send emails through your Rails App.

**NOTE**
It should be noted that there are a few things you'll need to change for production. For example, sending the Newsletter to ALL of your users is bad practice. You should consider creating a boolean value that they can check if they'd like to receive the Newsletter, and then sending it to all of those users.

**The steps:**

1. Create the scaffold for the Newsletter and the Mailer you'll use for it.
2. Create a custom method for your Newsletter class that you'll call when you press the "Send this Newsletter by Email" button.
3. Modify your mailer to create an action that will send your Newsletter to all of your users.
4. Create the mailer's view.
5. Add the route that you'll use for the "Send this Newsletter" button.
6. Add the link to the Newsletter's `show.html.erb` that will allow your client to send the Newsletter out.

**STEP 1. Generating a scaffold and a mailer**

I'm assuming you can do most of this yourself.

Be sure to give your mailer a different name than your scaffold, otherwise you'll run into some conflicts. I've chosen `Newsletter` for my scaffold and `Monthly` for my mailer.

```
$ rails g scaffold Newsletter subject:string body:text link:string

$ rails g mailer Monthly
```

**STEP 2. Create a custom method in `NewslettersController`**

Next, create a method that'll be called when your client wants to send the Newsletter out. The alternative is to just append this code to the `NewslettersController#create` method, but then the Newsletter cannot be modified before it's sent.

```
  def send_newsletter

#Let's take a close look at this line below
    Monthly_Mailer.monthly(@newsletter).deliver_now

    flash[:notice] = "Newsletter has been sent."
    redirect_to newsletter_path(@newsletter.id)
  end
```

**NOTES:**
`Monthly_Mailer` references the name of the file in `/app/mailers` that was created when you generated your mailer.
`monthly` references the method that will send the mailer that we'll create inside `Monthly_Mailer`

**STEP 3: Modify your mailer**

```
class Monthly_Mailer < ApplicationMailer
    def monthly(newsletter)
        @newsletter = newsletter
        mail to: User.pluck(:email)
    end
end
```

Change `User.pluck(:email)` to your own mailing list, possibly using the suggestion in the intro notes. As of right now, this bit of code sends the mailer to ALL users, even if they don't want the newsletter. That, in combination with the fact that there's no `Unsubscribe` link in the emails means it's unethical and may violate the law.

**STEP 4: Create the mailer's view**

When you generated your mailer it should've created a folder `monthly_mailer` in your `/app/views/` directory. Depending on the options you used for the generator, it may have even created a `monthly.html.erb` and a `monthly.text.erb`. If not, create those now. You'll have to do the styling for the HTML file yourself, but I've included some basic stuff. The TEXT file will be used as an alternative to the HTML file and will not include any HTML styling. I highly recommend you include both a HTML and a TEXT version.

Your `monthly.html.erb` file may look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p><%= @newsletter.subject %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.body %></p>
    <p><%= @newsletter.link %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For the `monthly.text.erb`, imagine the same as the HTML file, but without any HTML.

**STEP 5: Add the route that'll be used for the "Send this Newsletter by Email link.**

```
get :send_newsletter, to: 'newsletters#send_newsletter', as: :send_newsletter
```

`newsletters#send_newsletter` references the custom method that we made in our `NewslettersController`

**STEP 6: Add the link in the Newsletter's show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Send Newsletter by email", :controller => "newsletters", :action => "send_newsletter", :id => @newsletter %>
```

**STEP 7**

There is no step 7. Enjoy. Please feel free to submit corrections or suggestions. I know this isn't perfect, but it works.